# Ball on a Table

Tags: forces, reference-frames, acceleration, friction, velocity

A ball is moved on a table with some velocity . Lets take the ' Table + Ball " as the system . Now , the friction between the table and the ball is an internal force .

> **$\sum$** **F**<sub>**ext**</sub> = **Rate of change of Linear momentum**

As the ball slows down , the momentum of the system decreases . Which external force is responsible for this change in momentum ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What stops the table from slipping is that external force. The static friction between table and ground (the floor).

Comment: between table and ground ?

Comment: @InquisitiveMind Yup.

Comment: How ? the system is ball and table

Comment: @InquisitiveMind Then the friction between "table" and "floor" is external. We need external forces to reduce the total momentum.

Comment: understood  it  now .

Answer (score 0):

if we think that the system is moving in space, then the decrease in momentum is caused by the loss of kinetic energy due to heat which is generated by the system itself from the friction.

Comment: Acceleration of Center of Mass immediately implies that an external force is acting.